# How can I give someone permission to whitelist IPs on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions

In our company we have several people who need read-only access to the data via remote SQL queries into our AWS PostgreSQL database.

Right now, we manage our database permissions via whitelisted IPs. We have one user who needs access to the data, but their IP changes frequently.  We would like to give him control of whitelisting and removing IPs from the whitelist.

Is there any way to give him this level of permission?

Comment: you can use VPN for allowing him to your local network and open access of DB from your local network.

Comment: Why not write this as an answer and I can mark it as answering my question?